# Applying Drag, Snap Back Into Original Position To An Array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I am attempting to drag a movie clip and then have it snap back into its original position after being released. I want to apply this functioniality to an array with actionscript3.  Here is the code so far:

```
var dragArray:Array = new Array;
dragArray.push(blockSmalla);
dragArray.push(blockSmallb);
dragArray.push(blockSmallc);
dragArray.push(blockSmalld);
dragArray.push(blockSmalle);

var startPosition:Point;
function drag(e:Event):void {
dragArray[i].startDrag();
startPosition = new Point( dragArray[i].x, dragArray[i].y);
}
function dragStop(e:Event):void {
dragArray[i].stopDrag();

dragArray[i].x = startPosition.x;
dragArray[i].y = startPosition.y;
startPosition = null;
}

for (var i:uint = 0; i < dragArray.length; i++) {
dragArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
dragArray[i].stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dragStop);
}
```

The function is not being applied to the array.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Your question is very vague. If everything was working, you wouldn't be asking a question here. stating that it's "not working" is rather useless. Explain what result you expect and what result you get. On a related note, you should definitely learn about **scope**, **execution order** and the **currentTarget** / **target** properties that `Event` objects have. The variable `i` does not work the way you think it does.

Comment: I edited my question for you. Of course if was as compitant as you are, everything would certainly work. Unfortunately I am not. So I come to this community seeking useful answers. Thanks for taking time to comment, but a more helpful answer would be appreciated if you are able to provide such an answer.

Comment: Add a breakpoint in any of the functions, run the program with the debugger and see what value the variable `i` has when the program halts at that breakpoint . It's not a question of competence, but finding the difference between oneself's expectation of a result and the actual one. Also, understanding the aforementioned basics of programming _is_ useful and certainly will be in the future, too.

Comment: Noted. I will have more time to study and build better programming skills after the deadline on this project is met.  Since you cannot provide a specific answer or more detailed direction applied to what I am trying to do with my code, ill just seek what I need from someone else. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what null was trying to tell you is that within each function scope you should remove `dragArray[i]` and use `e.currentTarget` instead.
Here's a simple fix:

```
var dragArray:Array = new Array;
dragArray.push(blockSmalla);
dragArray.push(blockSmallb);
dragArray.push(blockSmallc);
dragArray.push(blockSmalld);
dragArray.push(blockSmalle);

var startPosition:Point;
function drag(e:Event):void {
    e.currentTarget.startDrag();
    startPosition = new Point( e.currentTarget.x, e.currentTarget.y);
}
function dragStop(e:Event):void {
    e.currentTarget.stopDrag(); 
    e.currentTarget.x = startPosition.x;
    e.currentTarget.y = startPosition.y;
    startPosition = null;
}

for (var i:uint = 0; i < dragArray.length; i++) {
    dragArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
    dragArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dragStop);
}
```

Also note I removed the stage reference on your MouseUp listener.

Comment: Ah, I see Karmacon.  Thank you so much.  I will do more study on this after the project is done.  Works properly now.